# How to ret with jxx in x64dbg's sciprt

Tags: x64dbg

```
main:
    call foo
    call bar
    ret

foo:
    // code

    cmp $number, 0
    je ret

    // code
    ret

bar:
    // code

    cmp $number, 0
    je ret

    // code
    ret
```

I would like to write a script like above. I looked it up, but I don't think there's a proper way.

So I have to jump between labels instead of calling.

```
main:
    jmp foo

foo:
    // code

    cmp $number, 0
    je bar

    // code

    jmp bar

bar:
    // code

    cmp $number, 0
    je ret

    // code
    ret
```

Is there good way to return when some flag is triggered?

Comment: you need to have a label before ret to jump to it